# data structure to store n-tuple keys

Tags: data-structures

I need a good data structure to store the following data:

The data are key,value pairs. However, more than one value maps to one key and the key is an n-tuple with n constant. Here's an example:

```
        key        | values
 (k1, k2, k3, k4)  | v1, v2, v3
 (k5, k6, k7, k8)  | v4, v5
```

A value is an object. The following characteristics are preferred in the data structure:

**The key should be easily searchable and new values should be easily entered.** Given a new key value pair, the program should be able to easily search the data structure to see if the key already exists, and if so, the new value should be added to the values list. If not, a new entry in the data structure should be created.

**one value should be easily deleted**

**the entire data structure should be easily deleted**

Any suggestions for such data structures are appreciated!

Comment: Use a hash table.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you! can you suggest a hash function that is suitable for this?

Comment: Whatever python uses.

Comment: If you need to scan the keys in sorted order, try a btree or other kinds of trees. If not, hash table as Yuval said. Most likely your language will have this construct already (ie, C++ STL, python dict, etc).

Comment: your keys are more than values what exactly you wanna to say

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to say? Keys are more than values?

Comment: i means that the k is much in quantity than that of i

Comment: Is there any special relationship between partially-related keys? For example, if `(k1,k2,k3,k4)` is a key, will you be especially interested in other keys of the form `(k1,k2,k3,something)`? Otherwise why not use whatever your language has for a map/dictionary/hashtable/whatever-it's-called-in-your-language.